# Hide link formatting Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-webextensions

I'm building a Mozilla Firefox extension to hide link's formatting and show them as regular text. It consists of a script that runs on web-pages (`content.js`) that's activated by clicking on the extension (handled with `background.js`). On activation, a CSS rule is injected to hide link's formatting. Activating it again will shut changes off.

`background.js` additionally updates the extension's icon (based on links being currently hidden or not) every time the active tab is changed.

I'm new to JavaScript. I'd really appreciate your comments and observations to improve it (best practices, code structure, etc).

Script that runs on web pages (content.js):

```
'use strict';

// Links formatting state variable
let hideLinks = false;
const hideLinksRule = `
a,
a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active,
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: inherit !important;
    background-color: inherit !important;
    border-bottom: initial !important;
}`;


let styleSheet = (function () {
    let style = document.createElement('style');
    document.head.appendChild(style);
    return style.sheet;
})();


function handleRequest(request) {
    
    // Do not modify if request is only a query
    if (request.isQuery) {
        return Promise.resolve({
            hideLinks
        });
    }

    // Toggle hide/show link formatting
    if (hideLinks) {
        styleSheet.deleteRule(0);
        hideLinks = !hideLinks;
    } else {
        styleSheet.insertRule(hideLinksRule, 0);
        hideLinks = !hideLinks;
    }

    // Return links state
    return Promise.resolve({
        hideLinks
    });

}


browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(handleRequest);
```

Script to handle the extension on the browser (background.js):

```
// Icons paths
const showLinksIconPath = {
    path: 'icons/link-icon.png'
};
const hideLinksIconPath = {
    path: 'icons/broken-link-icon.png'
};


function onError(error) {
    browser.browserAction.setIcon(showLinksIconPath);
}


function updateIcon(response) {
    if (response.hideLinks) {
        browser.browserAction.setIcon(hideLinksIconPath);
    } else {
        browser.browserAction.setIcon(showLinksIconPath);
    }
}


function verifyTabStatus(activeInfo) {
    browser.tabs.sendMessage(
        activeInfo.tabId, {
            isQuery: true
        }
    ).then(updateIcon).catch(onError);
}


function activeTabLinkToggle() {
    browser.tabs.query({
        currentWindow: true,
        active: true
    }).then(requestLinkFormatToggle).catch(onError);                
}


function requestLinkFormatToggle(tabs) {
    
    if (!(tabs === undefined || tabs.length == 0)) {
        const activeTab = tabs[0];
        browser.tabs.sendMessage(
            activeTab.id, {
                isQuery: false
            }
        ).then(updateIcon).catch(onError);
    }

}


// Update Icon on tab change
browser.tabs.onActivated.addListener(verifyTabStatus);


// Request toggle link formatting on click
browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(activeTabLinkToggle);
```

Configuration file to put it together (manifest.json):

```
{

    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "No-link",
    "version": "1.0",

    "description": "Hide link formatting.",

    "icons": {
        "48": "icons/link-icon.png"
    },


    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
    ],


    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icons/link-icon.png",
        "default_title": "No-link"
    },


    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["content.js"]
        }
    ]

}
```

You can also get the source code [here](https://github.com/fabrizzio-gz/no-link).
Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Always prefer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/278652/how-much-should-i-be-using-let-vs-const-in-es6) `const`** when declaring variables - only use `let` when you have to reassign a variable. `const` requires less cognitive overhead, when you know at a glance that something's never going to be reassigned.

**Style toggling** You're currently toggling the style with `styleSheet.insertRule(rule, 0)` and `styleSheet.deleteRule(0)`. I think it would be a *little* bit better to take a different approach.

- Who knows what `insertRule(rule, 0)` and `deleteRule(0)` do at a glance? Probably not a whole lot of people; it's not a very common API that's used.
- What if you need to expand the extension to add *additional* rules? Then using multiple rule indicies could become repetitive.

One alternative would be to, on toggle, either append or remove the `style` tag from the `<head>`. Another alternative would be to assign or clear its `textContent`. See below for example.

**hideLinks** is not an altogether precise name. At first glance, someone seeing a variable named `hideLinks` would probably think it sounds like a *function* that, when called, hides links. Maybe call it something else, like `linksAreHidden`. You can also make its toggling more DRY:

```
if (hideLinks) {
    styleSheet.deleteRule(0);
    hideLinks = !hideLinks;
} else {
    styleSheet.insertRule(hideLinksRule, 0);
    hideLinks = !hideLinks;
}
```

can be

```
if (hideLinks) {
    styleSheet.deleteRule(0);
} else {
    styleSheet.insertRule(hideLinksRule, 0);
}
hideLinks = !hideLinks;
```

Or, even better, rather than having a persistent outside variable, you could simply check to see whether the style element is attached or has content. See below for example. This is what I'd prefer - let the style node (which must exist regardless) be the source of truth, rather than introducing another variable that needs to stay in sync.

**Request object** You currently have

```
if (request.isQuery) {
    return Promise.resolve({
        hideLinks
    });
}
// otherwise, insert or remove style rule
```

I think it'd be better to be more explicit. What if you add a 3rd request command, or a 4th request command? Instead of having an implicit "*Else, if this isn't a query, then do THIS instead*", I'd prefer to always send a property indicating what the command should be.

Perhaps like this, using a `isToggle` property:

```
const hideLinksStyleText = `
a,
a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active,
a:visited {
text-decoration: none !important;
color: inherit !important;
background-color: inherit !important;
border-bottom: initial !important;
}`;
const styleTag = document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('style'));

function handleRequest(request) {
    const linksOriginallyHidden = Boolean(styleTag.textContent);
    // Do not modify if request is only a query
    if (request.isQuery) {
        return Promise.resolve({
            linksAreHidden: linksOriginallyHidden
        });
    }
    if (request.isToggle) {
        styleTag.textContent = linksOriginallyHidden
            ? hideLinksStyleText
            : '';
        return Promise.resolve({
            linksAreHidden: !linksOriginallyHidden
        });
    }
}
```

**The conditional operator** can be used to make conditional expressions tersely. This:

```
const showLinksIconPath = {
    path: 'icons/link-icon.png'
};
const hideLinksIconPath = {
    path: 'icons/broken-link-icon.png'
};
function updateIcon(response) {
    if (response.hideLinks) {
        browser.browserAction.setIcon(hideLinksIconPath);
    } else {
        browser.browserAction.setIcon(showLinksIconPath);
    }
}
```

can turn into

```
function updateIcon(response) {
    browser.browserAction.setIcon({
        path: `icons/${response.hideLinks ? 'broken-' : ''}link-icon.png`
    });
}
```

Or, if you don't like the interpolation:

```
function updateIcon(response) {
    browser.browserAction.setIcon({
        path: response.hideLinks
            ? 'icons/broken-link-icon.png'
            : 'icons/link-icon.png'
    });
}
```

**Tab checking** You have:

```
if (!(tabs === undefined || tabs.length == 0)) {
  const activeTab = tabs[0];
```

The negations are slightly tougher to parse logically at a glance than they can be. Consider instead:

```
if (tabs && tabs.length) {
```

In a larger project, you could use optional chaining and Babel:

```
if (tabs?.length) {
```

But optional chaining is only supported in very new versions of FF, and Babel isn't worth it *just* for this. (Babel is a good idea if you want to write a reasonably sized script *and* want to permit older browser versions to be able to understand the JS syntax you use. For a FF extension, it's less important, because almost all users will be on reasonably up-to-date browsers anyway - no need to transpile down to ES5 for those crummy IE11 users)

Comment: Thank you very much for your recommendations. One question, the `!` operator here `const linksOriginallyHidden = !styleTag.textContent;` is to verify if the string is empty?

Comment: Yep, that inverts the truthyness of the following expression. `!someText` evaluates to `true` if `someText` contains the empty string. Otherwise, it'll evaluate to `false` if `someText` contains any other string.

Comment: Right. Since links are hidden when the `textContent` isn't empty, I believe the condition should be inverted then: `const linksOriginallyHidden = !!styleTag.textContent;`. However, I ran across the formatting not changing anymore when I used a double `!!`. I don't know if I have a bug somewhere else or if it has anything to do with the style tag being an object and casting its properties to a boolean. The funny thing is that when I use a single `!` as in your script, it works but the icons are inverted (it shows a hidden-links icon when they aren't and vice-versa).

Comment: Oops, `linksOriginallyHidden` should be assigned the truthyness of the original `textContent`, not the other way around. Make sure that the object property names match up, eg `linksAreHidden` in both the content script and background script.

Comment: Yes, I found the problem. This assignment needed to be inverted as well: `styleTag.textContent = linksOriginallyHidden ? '', hideLinksStyleText';`. Thanks again for all of your observations! I'm working on implementing them. It's a nice improvement and I learned new things.